# Search if point is inside bbox in MongoDB

Tags: point, extents, mongodb

I am having difficulty finding away to search if a user current geo location is inside a bbox array that is stored in MongoDB.

For example I want to see if the following `174.763336, -36.848461` is inside any of the bbox from the documents stored in mongodb

As you can see from below the above should return New Zealand however its not returning anything.

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "place_id": 298186572,
    "osm_type": "relation",
    "osm_id": 556706,
    "display_name": "New Zealand",
    "place_rank": 4,
    "category": "boundary",
    "type": "administrative",
    "importance": 0.7917111729593472,
    "address": {
      "country": "New Zealand",
      "country_code": "nz"
    }
  },
  "bbox": [
    -179.059153,
    -52.8213687,
    179.3643594,
    -29.0303303
  ],
 
}
```

My MongoDB Query code

```
[{
 $match: {
  bbox: {
   $geoWithin: {
    $center: [
     [
      174.763336,
      -36.848461
     ],
     1000
    ]
   }
  }
 }
}]
```

The above returns in the following order: Australia, New Zealand and then the rest of the documents.